# efficient way for dynamic conversion during upload and download with Windows and Unix

Tags: java, windows, jsp, unix, file-upload

Requirement is to `Upload` one or more files of any type (like `txt,zip,doc,csv,xls`,...) from `Window` to `Unix` system using `JSP/Java` webpage. System dynamically has to convert the `Char-set`, `EOL`, etc... things from `Windows` to `Unix` supported format.

Note: uploading file may also be in Unix format.

Likewise if the user wants to download the same file(s) or different file(s) (exist in Unix filesystem), it has to be converted to `Windows` supported format.

I tried, writing a perl script to convert both ways.
After/before uploading/downloading files, the system will invoke appropriate script to convert the format.

**dos2unix.sh**

```
perl -pi -e 's/\r\n?/\n/g' filename
```

**unix2dos.sh**

```
perl -i -p -e 's/\n/\r\n/' filename
```

I need to achieve this conversion process in efficient way. Because, I am not sure about user file-size (max file-size allowed 5MB/file), number of files are uploaded in single submit (max 5 files).

Please suggest how to achieve with less cost.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What are you writing? A source code version control system or an FTP site?

Answer (score 7):

You are absolutely wasting your time because

1. There are already tools like `dos2unix` and `unix2dos`.
2. A decent text editor does not care about the line endings.
3. You do not know the difference between text and binary files.

Comment: I can't request my client to use decent text editor. but I will able to find whether text or binary files.

Comment: You cannot detect what your client is on because `User-Agent` can be easily spoofed. How are you planning to detect whether this is a binary or text file?

Comment: Nope! I didn't mean in that sense. But we requested to restrict `text` files in specific format(ex: `*.txt`) else binary.

Comment: You should then consider reading the input stream from the request, process it on the fly and write it to your backend store. Byte-by-byte with a buffered output stream.

Comment: Isn't time consuming? when the user uploading 5MB*5 files at the same time.

Comment: What did you expect? It won't get any faster than in `O(n)` (linear time). Of couse, you can examine the source of `unix2dos`.

Comment: @Mohamed Saligh: You really expect users to upload 5MB files of plain text?

Comment: I'm sensing this site is on an intranet.  You might want to consider using FTP.

Answer (score 0):

doc and xls you can skip, those aren't truly text files anyway, and any program that can render an xls or doc file should read and write it the same way.

Of the file extensions you listed, txt and csv are the only ones that are truly text.  As mentioned by Michael-O, dos2unix - the binary, not the perl shell perl script you listed above- would be a reasonable choice and likely much faster than a perl one-liner.  Another perfectly reasonable choice is to skip the conversion altogether, but that is a business decision, not a technical one.

zip files you could extract and then run them through the same filter process as your text files, i.e., txt and csv, then zip then back up.  But again, this seems like an awfully burdensome process.